# archiveArtifacts a specific file depending on build parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifact

I want to archive a specific JSON file that's name depends on the parameter passed in build, but I get the error
`` WorkflowScript: 42: unexpected char: '`' ``
what's the correct way to go about this?

```
archiveArtifacts artifacts: `closureV2_${params.env.split('/')[3]}.json`, onlyIfSuccessful: false
```

Would .split('/')[3] even work in a jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Jenkinsfile which uses Groovy as program language, Groovy not use ` for string expression.

Please change to

```
"closureV2_${params.env.split('/')[3]}.json"
```